# Magento add attribute inventory and tie in to size

Tags: magento, attributes, inventory

I can add the product size with a dropdown. But I an mot seeing how to add a inventory figure and then how do they connect?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `configurable products` from backend , check below links for more information :

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-create-configurable-product.html#gref

https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/

Comment: thank you for the reply fresher, I understand the backend and adding but in adding an inventory amount I don't see how to add the quantity into any of the equation that are offered in the drop down. Should this not be a form field so you can type amounts, ideally it would deduct as item is sold. Or am I trying to get to much from what is intended in this attribute.

Comment: @RonGin Go to `Catalog > Manage Products > cick on any product > on left side you can see Inventory > clcik on that, you can see Qty` that is the textfield, you can add any quesntity to the product there, if you are not asking this one, can please edit the question with details what exactly you want , so that you will get answer soon.....